# BadTokenException with YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am having heavy issues when using `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`

It works fine as long as I am connected to my WiFi, but once I switch to mobile data connection, after a few seconds of successful playback, the fragment seems to try to display some dialog, but fails to do so.

Here is the exception:

```
       android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.player.ar.a(SourceFile:83)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.player.Director.a(SourceFile:75)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.player.m.a(SourceFile:1205)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.async.a.f.a(SourceFile:185)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.async.k.a(SourceFile:35)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.async.ba.run(SourceFile:96)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is how the fragment is instantiated:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youtubeFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    youtubeFragment.initialize(getString(R.string.id_youtube),
            new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {


                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer,
                                                    boolean
                                                            b) {
                    mYouTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
                    mYouTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
                    next();
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                    YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.video_wrapper, youtubeFragment).commit();
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Goddchen

Comment: What version of Android and the YouTube app are you running ? Is the problem reproducible with just the YouTube app on your device?

Comment: Hey Jarek :) The Youtube app itself is running fine and has version 4.2.16, I'm running Android 4.2.1.

Comment: maybe a context problem, but i dont have time to investigate further ;(

Comment: Well, I'm not doing anything while this occurs, I'm not even touching the phone, so the Activity's lifecycle shouldn't experience any changes. And the fragment itself gets its Context when it is added to the FragmentManager, right? That would be the last line of my sample code above.
And it would be strange since it works fine when connected to WiFi.

Comment: I just founnd out that is is related to the videos that are played, one that triggeres the error is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHD8xzyvroo But I cannot find anything special/problematic about it :(